# Can I change the license of a forked project from LGPLv3 to MIT?

Tags: mit, license-compatibility, lgpl, relicensing, forking

I have forked a project with LGPLv3 license and I did there a lot of changes.
Can I distribute a new version under the MIT license?

Or only the possibility is to write the code from "scratch"?

Alternatively: To which license is it possible to migrate, from LGPLv3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

You will have to do a [clean-room implementatio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_room_design)n of the substitute MIT-licensed library. That means to not look at all on the existing library except the public interface defintion. You might have made this approach already impossible by looking at the existing code. If you look at the existing code, it usually can be considered already a derivative.

See also this related question https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/151515/rewrote-gnu-gpl-v2-code-in-another-language-can-i-change-a-license

Comment: To answer the last part of the question, LGPLv3 does permit relicensing to straight GPLv3.

Comment: Seems like something is wrong in the system or some software. For example, https://github.com/ethereum/trinity (MIT) came from Ethereum - LGPLv3 (compared dates and code) and https://github.com/hyperledger/besu (Apache License 2.0) came from the same. From this discussion, it looks like they broke the LGPLv3 license.